# Distribution of an intersection between a Poisson point process and a random set

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $D$ be a Poisson Point Process on $\mathbb{R}$ of rate $\lambda > 0$. Suppose $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a continuous time Markov Chain taking values $\{0,1\}$. The chain and the point process are independent. Now define:

$Z = \int_0^1\ 1_{\{X_t = 1\}} dt $

I wonder if it's true that:

$|D \cap \{ t :X_t = 1, t \in [0,1]\}| \sim |D \cap [0,Z]| $

I guess it is true and one way I tried to approach this problem is to condition both events $\{|D \cap \{ t :X_t = 1, t \in [0,1]\}| = k \}$ and $\{|D \cap [0,Z]| = k \}$ on the jumping times $\{\tau_i\}_{i \geq 0}$ of the chain. But I can show the equality only conditioned on the times assuming specific values, i.e. $\{\tau_i=r_i \; \; \forall i\geq0\}$ for some $\{r_i\} \in \mathbb{R}$, which I guess it's not enough. Any thoughts on how I can go from this to prove claim?

Comment: You have not fully specified the Markov Chain. If you were to give the associated probability matrix we are able to answer this question.

Comment: At first there shouldn't be any hypothesis on the transitions probabilities.

Comment: The notation $D \cap [0,Z]$ is weird since $D$ is not a set but a process. Therefore it is not clear to me exactly what you mean. Do however note that 
Note that if we have $X_t=1$ on $t \in [0,\frac{1}{3}]$ and on $[\frac{2}{3},1]$ and we have $X_t=0$ on $t \in (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3})$
we will have $Z=\frac{2}{3}$ so $[0,Z]=[0, \frac{2}{3}]$,while $\{ t :X_t = 1\}=[0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup  [\frac{2}{3},1]$ so at least we know $[0,Z] \neq \{ t :X_t = 1\}$ in general.

Comment: Thanks form commenting that! I realized that I should be talking about the distribution of the cardinality of the sets, and the question is now edited. But regarding your comment, a Poisson Point Process $D$ can be viewed as a random discrete subset of the real line, with the property that, for any Lebesgue measurable $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $\mathbb{P}(|D \cap A| = k) = \frac{[\lambda l(A)]^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda l(A)}$ where $\lambda > 0$ is the intensity of the process and $l$ is the Lebesgue measure. So, in your example, the process would be identically distributed.